# could you please help me in optimizing the following table?

Tags: tables, multicolumn, multirow, overleaf

Could you please help me to:  Solve the error which is undefined    control sequence, merge the two tables together(one table), letting the table to be in A4 page

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[paperheight=11in,paperwidth=7in, margin=0.5in,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
%\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multirow{Roadmap} & \multirow{February} & Week1 & \multirow{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Installing the simulation environment \\ Adding the UR manipulator to the simulation environment \\ Getting familiar with the simulation environment(learning how to include and position simple objects cube, ball, ect.)\end{tabular}}                                                                             \\ \cline{3-3}
                          &                           & Week2 &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   \\ \cline{3-4} 
                          &                           & Week3 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Literature studies on grasping a cube and navigating between two waypoints\\ Documentation\end{tabular}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                \\ \cline{3-4} 
                          &                           & Week4 & \multirow{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Literature studies on grasping a cube and navigating between (set of) waypoints\\ Coding the navigation towards the position of the object\\ Coding the grasp to the object\\ Coding the navigation of the grasped object from it's initial position towards pre-defined target waypoint\\ Documentation\end{tabular}} \\ \cline{2-3}
                          & \multirow{March}    & Week1 &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   \\ \cline{3-4} 
                          &                           & Week2 & \multirow{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Literature studies on the cable implementation (reduced stiffness objects)\\ Implementing and Positioning the cable at a certain position in the workspace\\ Documentation\end{tabular}}                                                                                                                               \\ \cline{3-3}
                          &                           & Week3 &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   \\ \cline{3-4} 
                          &                           & Week4 & \multirow{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Coding the grasp to the cable and conducting the navigation from the initial to goal waypoint\\ Confirming the no drop of the cable during the navigation\\ Documentation \\---\\ \textit{Note: The items in this field are started to be applied in a fixed manner (No machine learning model to be developed). }\\ \textit{In case the fixed manner isn't giving sufficient results, an RL model to be developed, the task to be extended more three weeks} \\\textit{and the shortest path planning task to be eliminated}
                          \end{tabular}}                      \\ \cline{2-3}
                          & \multirow{April}    & Week1 &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   \\ \cline{3-4} 
                          &                           & Week2 & \multirow{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Literature studies on reinforcement learning (Deep deterministic policy gradient and Deep Q-learning)\\ Documentation\end{tabular}}                                                                                                                                                                                    \\ \cline{3-3}
                          &                           & Week3 &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   \\ \cline{3-4} 
                          &                           & Week4 & \multirow{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Developing a Reinforcement learning model to navigate the grasped cable to the predefined target waypoint\\ Documentation  \\
                          ---\\ \textit{Note: For the grasping task, the code developed in the March's 4th week will be} used\end{tabular}}                                                                                       \\ \cline{2-3}
                          & May                       & Week1 &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
% Please add the following required packages to your document preamble:
% \usepackage{multirow}
\begin{table}[]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multirow{Roadmap} & \multirow{May}    & Week2 & \multirow{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Inserting certain fixed object(s) to be considered as obstacle(s)\\ Reconstructing the reinforcement learning model\\ Retraining the reinforcement learning model\\ Documentation\end{tabular}} \\ \cline{3-3}
                          &                         & Week3 &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            \\ \cline{3-4} 
                          &                         & Week4 & \multirow{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Transforming the obstacles from fixed to dynamic\\ Reconstructing/Extending the reinforcement learning model\\ Retraining the reinforcement learning model\\ Documentation\end{tabular}}        \\ \cline{2-3}
                          & \multirow{June}   & Week1 &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            \\ \cline{3-3}
                          &                         & Week2 &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            \\ \cline{3-3}
                          &                         & Week3 &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            \\ \cline{3-4} 
                          &                         & Week4 & \multirow{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Literature studies on the shortest path planning and optimizing the energy consumption with reinforcement learning \\ Documentation\end{tabular}}                                               \\ \cline{2-3}
                          & \multirow{July}   & Week1 &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            \\ \cline{3-4} 
                          &                         & Week2 & \multirow{Reconstructing/Extending the reinforcement learning model to include the shortest path following}                                                                                                                          \\ \cline{3-3}
                          &                         & Week3 &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            \\ \cline{3-3}
                          &                         & Week4 &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            \\ \cline{2-4} 
                          & \multirow{August} & Week1 & \multirow{Documentation and Finalization}                                                                                                                                                                                            \\ \cline{3-3}
                          &                         & Week2 &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            \\ \cline{3-3}
                          &                         & Week3 &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            \\ \cline{3-3}
                          &                         & Week4 &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Uncomment the loading of `multirow` if you use the `\multirow` command, and add to the latter  the missing two arguments (number of rows and width).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a proposition for the first table, replacing the nested tabulars with a simpler `\makecell`:

```
   \documentclass{article}
            \pagestyle{empty}
            \usepackage[paperheight=11in,paperwidth=7in, margin=0.5in,landscape]{geometry}
            \usepackage{tikz}
            \usepackage{array}
            \usepackage{makecell}
            \usepackage{color, colortbl}
            \usepackage{multirow}
            \usepackage{hhline}
            \usetikzlibrary{calc}

            \begin{document}

                    \begin{table}[]
                    \centering
                    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
                        \hline
                        \multirow{25.66}{*}{Roadmap} & \multirow{7.5}{*}{February} & \multirow{-2}{*}{Week1} &\makecell[l]{Installing the simulation environment \\ Adding the UR manipulator to the simulation environment \\ Getting familiar with the simulation environment(learning how to include and position simple objects cube, ball, etc.)}\\[-3ex] \cline{3-3}
                         & & Week2 \\ \cline{3-4}
                          & & Week3 & \makecell[l]{ Literature studies on grasping a cube and navigating between two waypoints\\ Documentation} \\ \cline{3-4}
                          & & \multirow{-2}{*}{Week4} & \makecell[l]{Literature studies on grasping a cube and navigating between (set of) waypoints\\ Coding the navigation towards the position of the object\\ Coding the grasp to the object\\ Coding the navigation of the grasped object from it's initial position towards pre-defined target waypoint\\ Documentation} \\[-3ex] \cline{2-3}
                          & \multirow{10}{*}{March} & Week1 & \\ \cline{3-4}
                          & & \multirow{-2}{*}{Week2}& \makecell[l]{ Literature studies on the cable implementation (reduced stiffness objects)\\ Implementing and Positioning the cable at a certain position in the workspace\\ Documentation} \\[-3ex]
                          \cline{3-3}
                           & & Week3 \\
                          \cline{3-4}
                          & & \multirow{-2}{*}{Week4} & \makecell[l]{Coding the grasp to the cable and conducting the navigation from the initial to goal waypoint\\ Confirming the no drop of the cable during the navigation\\ Documentation \\---\\ \textit{Note: The items in this field are started to be applied in a fixed manner (No machine learning model to be developed). }\\ \textit{In case the fixed manner isn't giving sufficient results, an RL model to be developed, the task to be extended more three weeks} \\\textit{and the shortest path planning task to be eliminated}} \\[-2.75ex] \cline{2-3}
                          & \multirow{5.5}{*}{April} & Week1 & \\ \cline{3-4}
                          & & Week2 & \makecell[l]{Literature studies on reinforcement learning\\ (Deep deterministic policy gradient and Deep Q-learning)\\ Documentation} \\[-2.8ex] \cline{3-3}
                          & & Week3 & \\ \cline{3-4}
                          & & \multirow{-2}{*}{Week4} & \makecell[l]{Developing a Reinforcement learning model to navigate the grasped cable to the predefined target waypoint\\ Documentation \\
                          ---\\ \textit{Note: For the grasping task, the code developed in the March's 4th week will be} used} \\[-2.8ex] \cline{2-3}
                          & May & Week1 & \\ \hline
                    \end{tabular}
                    \end{table}

        \end{document}
```

[image]